# Help with Left Join

Tags: sql-server-2008

Below is my sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    U.[IP Address],
    U.[Risk Rating],
    COUNT( U.[IP Address] ) AS UNIXIP,
    COUNT( U.[Risk Rating] ) RATINGCOUNT
FROM
    Exception AS E
LEFT JOIN
    tblUNIX_Archive AS U
        ON E.IP_address <> U.[IP Address]  -- Is using '<>' ok? instead of =
        AND (U.ScanDate BETWEEN '2011-01-22' AND '2011-02-18')
group by
    U.[Risk Rating],
    U.[IP Address]
ORDER BY
    U.[Risk Rating],
    U.[IP Address]
```

i only need to see the unique IP Address that are not in Exception table that are in tblUNIX_Archive table.  I am getting multiple records.  What am I doing wrong with the above sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to select the records in one table that aren't in another you don't have to use join, you have to use NOT IN

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    U.[IP Address],
    U.[Risk Rating],
    COUNT( U.[IP Address] ) AS UNIXIP,
    COUNT( U.[Risk Rating] ) RATINGCOUNT
FROM
    tblUNIX_Archive AS U
where  U.[IP Address] NOT IN( select E.IP_address  from Exception AS E)
        AND (U.ScanDate BETWEEN '2011-01-22' AND '2011-02-18')
group by
    U.[Risk Rating],
    U.[IP Address]
ORDER BY
    U.[Risk Rating],
    U.[IP Address]
```

Comment: you can also try with a NOT EXISTS() query type instead of the NOT IN(). sometimes it has better performance depending on your selection of indexes

Answer (score 2):

@Einacio, while your solution will work, I think having NOT IN in the where clause is going to hit the performance - may be even badly if the records are more.

@Kombucha, here is what you can try:

```
    SELECT DISTINCT
    U.[IP Address],
    U.[Risk Rating],
    COUNT( U.[IP Address] ) AS UNIXIP,
    COUNT( U.[Risk Rating] ) RATINGCOUNT
FROM
    tblUNIX_Archive AS U
LEFT JOIN
    Exception AS E
        ON E.IP_address = U.[IP Address]  -- = to is better 
        AND (U.ScanDate BETWEEN '2011-01-22' AND '2011-02-18')
where E.IP_adress is null
group by
    U.[Risk Rating],
    U.[IP Address]
ORDER BY
    U.[Risk Rating],
    U.[IP Address]
```

Update: noticed that the joined tables were in the wrong order...corrected that.

Comment: This is a classic sql question on interviews.  Outer join = A+, not in/exists = C, something else = F.

Comment: @Nitin Singhai your solution works as well.  I LIKE it as much as the above solution by user92546.  I can only pick 1....  user92546 solution showed up first.  Thx 2u2 ;)

Answer (score 1):

A left outer join will return rows from the left table, even if they are unmatched by rows on the right.  Since you want all of the Unix IP addresses they should be on the left.  (Or switch to a right outer join.)  The WHERE clause rejects the matched rows.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    U.[IP Address],
    U.[Risk Rating],
    COUNT( U.[IP Address] ) AS UNIXIP,
    COUNT( U.[Risk Rating] ) RATINGCOUNT
FROM
    tblUNIX_Archive AS U left outer join
    Exception AS E ON E.IP_address = U.[IP Address] AND
        (U.ScanDate BETWEEN '2011-01-22' AND '2011-02-18')
WHERE
    E.IP_address is NULL
group by
    U.[Risk Rating],
    U.[IP Address]
ORDER BY
    U.[Risk Rating],
    U.[IP Address]
```

Comment: <3 it!!!!  work like a charm :)  thx a million for your help and tip for Left/Right Outer Join.  mwah! d best user92546